# Does "data property" have "access property" internally in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties

I understood that there are two types of property in object, data property and access property.

And we can access to "data property" without "access property" like this:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Pecan'
};

console.log(person.name) // getting name data property
person.name = 'Pie' // setting name data property
```

And I guess, when data property has created, access property has created internally with the "name" like this:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Pecan',

  get name() {
    return this.name;
  },
  set name(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Am I right?

Comment: in your 2nd example thats going to cause infinite recursion

Comment: There is no *magic getter* you don't need a getter, you don't have one.

Comment: No, data properties are not accessor properties under the hood

Comment: The ES spec [distinguishes between these two kinds of properties](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-attributes). You also cannot do something like `Object.defineProperty({}, "name", { value: "Pecan", get(){ return "Pecan" } });` (throws _“Uncaught `TypeError`: property descriptors must not specify a value or be writable when a getter or setter has been specified”_), and `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(person, "name")` unambiguously yields either a data property descriptor or an accessor property descriptor. Getters and setters are actual functions; there is no function with data properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I guess, when data property has created, access property has created internally

No, you're not right. A data property does not contain a getter/setter. And an accessor property does not contain a space to store a value. It's either one or the other, it's not like data properties are a layer over accessor properties or the other way round.

It might help to use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` to see what the two different ways of writing that object literal generate:

```js
const personData = {
  name: 'Pecan',
}

let personAccessorName = 'Pecan';
const personAccessor = {
  get name() {
    return personAccessorName ;
  },
  set name(name) {
    personAccessorName = name;
  }
};

console.log('data property', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(personData, 'name'));
console.log('accessor property', Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(personAccessor, 'name'));
```

```css
div.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%; }
```